# Understand Allocation of matrix c

Tags: c, memory-management, calloc

I have the following function:

```
float **alloc_float_matrix(int n) {
    int i;
    float **m = (float**)calloc(n, sizeof(float*));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m[i] = (float*)calloc(n, sizeof(float));
    }
    return m;
}
```

I want to find out why is this works

```
float **m = (float**)calloc(n, sizeof(float*));
```

And how will be memory allocated. 
What i want to see is the layout of addresses.
In this moment i think is:
m is pointing to an array of arrays.
And after that are the next n element for each array

> > m[1] m[2] m[3] m[4] m[5]... m[n] (row1)n[1] n[2] n[3] n[4] n[5] n[6] n[7] ...n[n] (row2)n[1] n[2] n[3] n[4] n[5] n[6] n[7] ...n[n]...

Is this representation correct?

Comment: no this representation is not correct,here m[1],m[2] ....m[n] represents the row1,row2 ...row[n] respectively and are in contiguous memory range.

Comment: so n[1] n[2] n[3] n[4] n[5] n[6] n[7] ...n[n]  is col?

Comment: you  can say so, because for m1...mn memory will be allocated in first memory allocation call.

Comment: so m[i] will hold a pointer to specific n[1] n[2] n[3] n[4] n[5] n[6] n[7] ...n[n] row?

Comment: yes right, for these pointer memory allocations will be done in second memory allocation call as per above code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you done here:

```
float **m = (float**)calloc(n, sizeof(float*));
```

1. You have created a pointer of type float**.
2. Then you assign this pointer the initial address of a sequential block of memory consisting of

   (n * sizeof(float*))

bytes. All these bytes have got the value of zero in them. You can address **n** elements now from this memory block, each holding

```
sizeof(float*)
```

bytes, i.e:

m[0], m[1], m[2], ... , m[n - 1]

where m[0] will return you the actual value of the first element from the memory block, which is a memory address.

3. The next thing you do is: you take each of these elements (m[0], m[1], etc.) and assign to **each** of them new different memory blocks at **different** memory locations. Each of these memory blocks consist of

   (n * sizeof(float*))

bytes and you can address n elements, where each element consists of

```
sizeof(float)
```

bytes, i.e:

(row 0) m[0][0], m[0][1], m[0][2], . . ., m[0][n - 1]

(row 1) m[1][0], m[1][1], m[1][2], . . ., m[1][n - 1]

.
.
.

(row n - 1) m[n - 1][0], m[n - 1][1], m[n - 1][2], . . ., m[n - 1][n - 1]

So overall, what you get is:
An array, m, that holds n consecutive memory addresses where each of those memory addresses point to **n** memory blocks all located at different addresses. Each of them hold

```
(n * sizeof(float))
```

bytes, all consecutive.
You cannot say that the next memory location after m[0][n - 1] is m[1][0], but you **can** say that the next memory location after m[0][n - 2] is m[0][n - 1]

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
float **m = (float**)calloc(n, sizeof(float*));
```

allocates n pointers of type float*.
In the next loop, all of the n float* are assigned to another n float*.

In the line mentioned above you first create n float-pointers that are like a one-dimensional array.
In the loop, all of these pointers are assigned to another n-sized 'array' and you get a nxn matrix.